# QGIS processing tools - saving/exporting graph

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-processing

I just tried QGIS processing tools for the first time.

When using shortest path search for the first time, the algorithm is building a path graph (of course). However, the graph is never re-used. Every time the algorithm is used, the graph building starts again. I am not familiar with the exact code used for it, but I guess the graph is network-wide, not related to the specific points I selected. So is there a way to re-use the graph? Er even export it to a file?

My network is large (more than 200k features), so efficiency is important. The network is rarely updated, so calculating a graph could easily be done just once in a while.

I looked up the docs and settings of processing tools, and this option seems to be unavailable (which is surprising). So maybe I am missing something, or maybe someone could suggest a way to serialize the graph and save it using python code? I am using QGIS 3.1 (A Coruna).

This is a programming question so I took liberty to repost it to [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60736269/9385654).

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the community @Sane. Is it possible for you to share a screenshot of what you are talking about? So that it may be easy to comprehend what you are asking.

Comment: @datakeen Done.

Comment: The result of this kind of processing adds a virtual shapefile consisting of a line feature between the two selected points, based on a network defined on another shapefile. If you are taking about to save the results, it is better to save the virtual file which normally has autogenerated name "Shortest path" on known location on a storage device. Or else you are talking about saving and exporting it to attach in another document, you should go to Layout Manager, adjust the look of your map and then export it to image formate of your choice.

Comment: Thank you datakeen, the problem however is the graph building (some kind of internal, abstract object of the procedure) and execution time, not the result.